# Joining Two Dataframes: Lost tasks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have time series data in a PySpark DataFrame. Each of my signals (`value` column) should be assigned a unique `id`. However the `id` values are imprecise and need to be extended to both sides. The original DataFrame looks like this:

```
df_start
+------+----+-------+
| time | id | value |
+------+----+-------+
|     1|   0|    1.0|
|     2|   1|    2.0|
|     3|   1|    2.0|
|     4|   0|    1.0|
|     5|   0|    0.0|
|     6|   0|    1.0|
|     7|   2|    2.0|
|     8|   2|    3.0|
|     9|   2|    2.0|
|    10|   0|    1.0|
|    11|   0|    0.0|
+------+----+-------+
```

The desired output is:

```
df_desired
+------+----+-------+
| time | id | value |
+------+----+-------+
|     1|   1|    1.0|
|     2|   1|    2.0|
|     3|   1|    2.0|
|     4|   1|    1.0|
|     6|   2|    1.0|
|     7|   2|    2.0|
|     8|   2|    3.0|
|     9|   2|    2.0|
|    10|   2|    1.0|
|    11|   2|    1.0|
+------+----+-------+
```

So there are two things happening here:

- The `id` column is not *precise* enough: Each `id` starts logging a (here 1 and 1) time steps to late, and ends b time steps (here 1 and 2) to early. I therefore have to replace some zeros with their respective id.
- After 'padding' the entries in the `id` column, I remove all remaining rows with `id=0`. (Here only for row with `time=5`.)

Luckily I know, for each Id, what the relative logging time delay is. Currently, I convert this to the absolute, correct logging times in

```
df_join
+----+-------+-------+
| id | min_t | max_t |
+----+-------+-------+
|   1|      1|      4|
|   2|      6|     11|
+----+-------+-------+
```

which I use to then 'filter' the original data using a join

```
df_desired = df_join.join(df_start, 
                          df_start.time.between(df_join.min_t, df_join.max_t)
                         )
```

which results in the desired output.

In reality `df_join` has at least 400 000 rows and `df_start` has about 10 billion rows, of which we keep most.

When I run this on our cluster, I am at some point getting warnings like `Lost task, ExecutorLostFailure, Container marked as failed, Exit code: 134`.

I suspect the executors are running out of memory, however I have not found any solution.

Comment: Some comments: I have tried to increase the value for the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions, I have tried to force a broadcast join, tried to repartition the data cleverly, tried to write my own udfs or maps for filtering which access the smaller df_join as a broadcasted variable. However, none of it worked.

Comment: How much memory did you assign to driver and executor?

Comment: I specify the following options: "--num-executors 8 --executor-memory 8704M --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 5G".